# Spring WS: Why is Spring WS returning WebServiceTransportException instead of a SoapFaultException

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I have the problem when calling my webservice, that Spring WS is returning just a WebServiceTransportException: Internal Server Error instead of the expected SoapFaultException. When I trigger the call in SOAPUI I get the soap fault.

The WebServiceTransportException surpresses also the output of the response, so I don't see in the logs what the problem was.

I use Spring WS in a spring boot application with Configuration classes.

```
public class SoapClientConfig {

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SoapClientConfig.class);

private static final int DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 60000;
private static final int DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 60000;
private static final int DEFAULT_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE = 2;

public static final int CONNECTION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 30000;

@Value("${soap.client.proxy.host}")
protected String proxyHost;
@Value("${soap.client.proxy.port}")
protected String proxyPort;
@Value("${soap.client.max.connections}")
private int maxConnections;

public Jaxb2Marshaller createMarshaller(String packageName) throws Exception {
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller.setContextPath(packageName);
    jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jaxb2Marshaller;
}

public WebServiceTemplate createWebServiceTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller, ClientInterceptor securityInterceptor, WebServiceMessageSender messageSender) {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(messageSender);
    if(securityInterceptor != null) {
        webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors((ClientInterceptor[]) Arrays.asList(securityInterceptor, createLoggingInterceptor()).toArray());
    } else {
        webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors((ClientInterceptor[]) Arrays.asList(createLoggingInterceptor()).toArray());
    }
    webServiceTemplate.setCheckConnectionForFault(false);
    webServiceTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
    return webServiceTemplate;
}

private ClientInterceptor createLoggingInterceptor() {
    return new SoapLoggingInterceptor();
}

public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor createSecurityInterceptor(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername(username);
    wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword(password);
    wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("UsernameToken");
    wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType("PasswordText");
    wss4jSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return wss4jSecurityInterceptor;
}

public HttpComponentsMessageSender createMessageSender() {
    return new HttpComponentsMessageSender(createHttpClient());
}

private HttpClient createHttpClient() {
    RequestConfig.Builder configBuilder = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS)
            .setSocketTimeout(DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(CONNECTION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
    addProxySettings(configBuilder);

    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(configBuilder.build());
    addInterceptor(clientBuilder);
    addConnectionManager(clientBuilder);

    return clientBuilder.build();
}

private void addProxySettings(RequestConfig.Builder configBuilder) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(proxyHost)) {
        configBuilder.setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, Integer.valueOf(proxyPort)));
    }
}

private void addInterceptor(HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder) {
    clientBuilder.addInterceptorFirst(new HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor());
}

private void addConnectionManager(HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder) {
    if (maxConnections > DEFAULT_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE) {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        cm.setMaxTotal(maxConnections);
        cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnections);
        clientBuilder.setConnectionManager(cm);
    }
}
```

When the request is correct everything works fine. But when the request contains errors I don't get the reason as the soap fault. Only the WebServiceTransportException.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Internal Server Error [500]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:699)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:609)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:378)
```

Comment: WebServiceTransportExceptin is thrown when there is problem connecting to the server. So, what is the error you're expecting here ? How do you know this exception swallowed the soap fault exception ? I think spring makes a distinction and throws IO exception instead of wrapping everything into a soap fault.

Comment: When I call the service with correct parameters it returns a valid response. But when I send the request with wrong parameters which causes a soapfault (e.g. when executing same request in soapui) I just get the WebServiceTransportException. This can't be a connection problem because I get a valid result with correct parameters. (With parameters I mean input for the web service)

Comment: Can you add a sample example where it is working and where it wont? I just wanted to see what triggered the internal server error. You can also inspect the response xml coming back to see if it has the fault payload in spring or else spring will wrap it as a transport error.

Comment: webServiceTemplate.setCheckConnectionForFault(false); try settting it to true. see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting

```
webServiceTemplate.setCheckConnectionForFault(true);
```

did the trick, instead of setting it to false like in the config class above.

Thanks Reddy for the hint in the right direction. I also missed to implement the handleFault method, so I couldn't see the response in the log. For all who want to see an example for an LoggingInterceptor:

```
public class SoapLoggingInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SoapLoggingInterceptor.class);

@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    ByteArrayTransportOutputStream os = new ByteArrayTransportOutputStream();
    try {
        messageContext.getRequest().writeTo(os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new WebServiceIOException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    String request = new String(os.toByteArray()).replaceAll("\n", "");
    log.info("Soap request\n----------------------------\n" + request + "\n----------------------------\n");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    logMessageContext(messageContext);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    logMessageContext(messageContext);
    return true;
}

private void logMessageContext(MessageContext messageContext) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        messageContext.getResponse().writeTo(os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new WebServiceIOException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    String response = new String(os.toByteArray());
    log.info("Soap response\n----------------------------\n" + response + "\n----------------------------\n");
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Exception e) throws WebServiceClientException {

}

class ByteArrayTransportOutputStream extends TransportOutputStream {

    private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream;

    @Override
    public void addHeader(String name, String value) throws IOException {
        createOutputStream();
        String header = name + ": " + value + "\n";
        outputStream.write(header.getBytes());
    }

    public byte[] toByteArray() {
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected OutputStream createOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (outputStream == null) {
            outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        }
        return outputStream;
    }
}
}
```